# Firebase Push Notifications not working on phone but works in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to get my remote push notifications to work on my phone. When I connect my phone to my computer and run the simulator through my phone, the notifications sent from the Firebase console works perfectly fine. However, when I uploaded it onto Testflight and downloaded it onto my phone, my push notifications aren't coming through.

My certificates are uploaded correctly and below is my code

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        FIRApp.configure()
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
                application,
                openURL: url,
                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                annotation: annotation)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)

        completionHandler(.NoData)
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print(error)
        print(error.description)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: were you able to test push notifications with production certificates? I'm having the same issue.  Ad-hoc builds would not receive push notifications from firebase.

Comment: btw, your screenshot only shows development certificates. Have you created production SSL certificates?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the APNs Distribution Cert and submit to Firebase console?

Please check this guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs#configure_an_app_id_for_push_notifications

*"The app is now enabled to use the Push Notification development environment. When you are ready to release your application, you need to enable the app to use the Push Notification production environment: repeat these steps, but click Create Certificate under the Production SSL Certificate section instead of Development SSL Certificate.
If you are calling setAPNSToken, make sure that the value of type is correctly set: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox for the sandbox environment, or FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd for the production environment. If you don't set the correct type, messages will not be delivered to your app."*

Comment: I do believe I have it :/ - i edited my original post to contain the image

Answer (score 0):

Any updates?

I found this solution in other forums. If you use Firebase, you have to add in:

With `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled: NO`

**TestFlight:**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
}
```

**Production:**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];
}
```

With `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled: YES`... In theory this is not necessary..